# Azure Maps Web SDK - Map controls tooltip always in English

Tags: azure-maps

When I set the atlas.Map language to 'fr', the map tiles are in French but all map control tooltips remain in English. (Zoom In, Reset to default rotation, map styles like Road or Hybrid etc.)

Is there another parameter to localize map controls tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

The team is aware of this issue and plan to update this  in a few months. When this is updated, if you are referencing the Azure Maps SDK's hosted scripts, rather then self hosting the NPM package, you will see the update in production occur automatically with no additional work required by you.

Comment: I use the npm package. Is there release notes somewhere for the azure-maps-control package ? It would be useful for knowing when an issue has been addressed.